# AngularJS modal dialog not opening

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

This is driving me nuts.  I fumbled around with converting a site to AngularJS about a year ago.  I got it to a livable state, although a bit tacky.  I'm trying to add a new page, which will use a modal dialog.  I have code with modal dialogs that work.  This one, for some reason, does not.  I'm finding the lack of debugging info in the console highly irritating.  Anywho, I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something.  I have cut the guts of the controller out... and the HTML for that fact as none of it is required for this.

Symptom: I hit "Create Alert" and nothing happens.  You can see the page itself [here](http://www.gamengai.com/bad_popup.html).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script>

angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller("alertController", ['$scope','$http','$sce','$location', function($scope,$http,$sce,$location) {
    $scope.data = "Hello World";
}]);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent_column" style="min-width: 700px; max-width: 700px; margin: 50px auto;" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="alertController">
{{data}}
            <span id="openModal" class="modalDialog" style="padding: 3px;">
                <div style="width: 250px;">
                    Modal!
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                </div>
            </span>

        <div class="ggButton" style="line-height: 135%;"><a href="#openModal">Create Alert</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You haven't referenced any javascript frameworks that provide modal dialog functionality (such as JQuery UI or Bootstrap), and your current code doesn't have any logic to hide or show the modal dialog. Can you see any javascript files in your project that might be needed as part of the solution?

Comment: Okay, my working example has jquery in it and another js file with the logic to display the popup.  This one doesn't.  I updated the bad_popup.html file with JQuery & the csspopup.js script, but it's still not working.  It's coming back to me but still not sure what's busted. BTW, a working example on the same server is at http://www.gamengai.com/popup.html

Comment: However, looking at the differences in bad_popup.html and popup.html, one can see the versions of angularjs are different.  If I change bad_popup to use version 1.3.0-rc.5 instead of 1.2.25, the modal part works (although I get an injection error.  There's a reason I used the later version (although I can't remember why).  The code is built around that so obviously I'd like to get that working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $location service is changing the url to:
http://www.gamengai.com/bad_popup.html#/openModal

But JQuery UI needs:
http://www.gamengai.com/bad_popup.html#openModal

Configure the $location service to not use the hashbang mode:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
})
.controller("alertController", ['$scope','$http','$sce', '$location',        
function($scope,$http,$sce, $location) {
    $scope.data = "Hello World";
}]);
```

"$location service has two configuration modes which control the format of the URL in the browser address bar: Hashbang mode (the default) and the HTML5 mode which is based on using the HTML5 History API. Applications use the same API in both modes and the $location service will work with appropriate URL segments and browser APIs to facilitate the browser URL change and history management."

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/guide/$location

Or if you don't need the location service, you could simply remove $location from your app:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller("alertController", ['$scope','$http','$sce', function ($scope,$http,$sce) {
    $scope.data = "Hello World";
}]);
```

More info here:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/guide/$location

Change the hyperlinks from href to ng-href:

```
<a ng-href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<a ng-href="#openModal">Create Alert</a>
```

Comment: @Kiss-O-Matic, I'm reloading bad_popup.html (spying on you as you fix the issue), change angular.module('myApp') to angular.module('myApp', []) to fix this error "Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.5/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp"

Comment: Okay - that does fix it.  The modal dialog pops up.   The problem is, in the actual code I believe I need sanitize.  If you look at bad_popup.html, you'll notice that {{data}} is no longer interpreted. :-/

Comment: Haha -- you're fast.  Okay, I made that change, but now the modal dialog is busted again.

Comment: change angular.module('myApp') to angular.module('myApp', []). The latter example creates the app when you pass an array as a second parameter. angular.module('myApp') by itself is looking for an app that already exists called myApp

Comment: I did that... check it out.  Same results though. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89498/discussion-between-kiss-o-matic-and-programmerguy).

Comment: Cheers for all that work -- I'd have never found it.